# ejs add comma every three digit

Tags: node.js, ejs

i'm using ejs for very small homepage

I wanna insert comma every three digit

#### Now situation

```
<%= product.price %> 
result = 1000000
```

#### I want like this

```
<%= product.price %> // some function
result 1,000,000
```

can you help me?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to print a number with commas as thousands separators in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901102/how-to-print-a-number-with-commas-as-thousands-separators-in-javascript)

Comment: yeah this is the one , but don't know how to use it in ejs 

Comment: thanks dude you gave me clue to solve it 

Answer (score 0):

self answer

just pass the function to ejs

```
[ express ]

res.render(`${__dirname}/views/dashboard.ejs`, {
   ✅ numberWithCommas ✅ : function (x) {
     return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ',');
   },
});
```

```
[ ejs ]
now you can call the function 

<%- numberWithCommas(product.price) %>

result
1,000,000
```